# Install snap packages with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am automating Canonical Kubernetes [installation](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-kubernetes-with-conjure-up#1) with Ansible. The intallation process required [snap](https://snapcraft.io/) to be present on the host.

Is there a standard way to install  snap packages with Ansible already?

Comment: just curious whether it would even be possible to accomplish the inverse:  install ansible using snap?  Instead of apt or yum.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `snap` module is available since version 2.8 of Ansible (released May 2019):

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/snap_module.html#snap-module

The required task will be:

```yaml
- name: Install conjure-up for Canonical Kubernetes
  community.general.snap:
    name: conjure-up
    classic: yes
```

Comment: Apparently you have to use `community.general.snap:` instead of `snap:` (from the docs you've linked) - just using snap throws an error.

Comment: And you need to install the respective collection from Ansible Galaxy, as well as per the linked documentation. And given this does nothing to expose all the many other features of `snap` (setting config values), I think I'll stick with `command`.

Comment: The link is dead, which would suggest the module has been removed from Ansible. Is that right?

Comment: @Petr there is currently a [bug in the Ansible documentation generation](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.general/issues/4876) which causes the 404 you are seeing. You can still view the docs in the [devel version of the page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel//collections/community/general/snap_module.html)

Answer (score 12):

There is no snap module for ansible yet. You can install snap packages by using `command` module.

```
- name: install heroku cli via snap
  command: snap install heroku --classic
```

Answer (score 1):

if you'd like to install multiple packages at once

```
# Install "foo" and "bar" snaps with common option com=A and specific options fooPar=X and barPar=Y
- name: Install "foo" and "bar" with options
  community.general.snap:
    name:
      - foo
      - bar
    options:
      - com=A
      - foo:fooPar=X
      - bar:barPar=Y
```